# Math.max.apply gives an error CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working on something for checking what is the max value and whats is the min value.  For this I am using `Math.max.apply()` and `Math.min.apply()`. 
Before I check that I convert an Object out of GeoJson code called from and to. 
That looks like this:

```js
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      [
       6.338356,
       52.790868
      ],
      [
       6.378572,
       52.648089
      ],
      [
       6.10522,
       52.663572
      ],
      [
       6.089325,
       52.798539
      ],
      [
       6.338356,
       52.790868
      ]
     ]
    ]
   },
   "properties": {
    "name": "DiggitTwoOne",
    "regioFacetId": "tcm:106-353682-1024",
    "level": 3,
    "from": "10",
    "to": "12"
   }
  },
  {
   "type": "Feature",
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      [
       6.105498,
       52.663816
      ],
      [
       6.378605,
       52.648187
      ],
      [
       6.417051,
       52.520692
      ],
      [
       6.173867,
       52.509454
      ],
      [
       6.105498,
       52.663816
      ]
     ]
    ]
   },
   "properties": {
    "name": "DiggitTwoTwo",
    "regioFacetId": "tcm:106-353682-1024",
    "level": 3,
    "from": "13",
    "to": "15"
   }
  }
  ]
}
```

For now the javascript code looks like this:

```js
var from = event.feature.getProperty("from");
var to = event.feature.getProperty("to");
var mergeObjects = JSON.parse(from,to);

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,mergeObjects));
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, mergeObjects));
```

When I run the javascript code it gives an error like this:
CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object.

I am using the Objects from and to.

Is there something I did wrong or am I getting it wrong of using it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `apply` accepts an array and you're not passing it that:

```
var from = event.feature.getProperty("from"),
    to = event.feature.getProperty("to"),
    numArr = [from, to];

Math.max.apply(Math, numArr);
Math.min.apply(Math, numArr);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, Thank you! That was totally what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help, @MissesA